# How can I globally register an npm package in nuxt 3

Tags: plugins, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

## Tried

```
// ~/plugins/components.js
import CraydelAlert from '@craydel-v3/craydel-alert/src/CraydelAlert'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(CraydelAlert)
})
```

## Expectation

When I use the `<craydel-alert></craydel-alert>` component on my page I expect it to be auto imported and identified automatically in the editor i'm using (PhpStorm) without locally registering it. It should automatically be shown in the IntelliSense as soon as I type the name of the component but it doesn't. Locally registering the component seems to work fine. So i'm not sure where i'm going wrong. As far as I know nothing should be done in nuxt.config since in Nuxt 3 anything in the plugins folder should be read automatically.

## Result

When building the app I get this error:

`[Vue warn]: A plugin must either be a function or an object with an "install" function.`